Permission denied using gitlab runner
When accessing ec2-user directory it shows 'Permission Denied' using gitlab runner.
stages:
    - build

pull-repository-job:
    stage: build
    tags:
        - ci
        - shell
    only:
        - master
    before_script:
        - cd /home/ec2-user/deployer/safety/httpdocs
    script:
        - echo "Start Deploy"
        - echo "Finished Build and Deploy"

When accessing the gitlab-runner directory there will be no error shown.

Here is the error message:
Running with gitlab-runner 17.1.0 (fe45d)
  on Gitlab Runner for safety 4zsL7mu-, system ID: s_ec27s2f
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on ip-10-10-132-.us-west-2.compute.internal...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/ec2-user’: Permission denied


gitlab-runner user and usergroup cannot access to ec2-user related directories if your gitlab-runner executed by gitlab-runner user. Try add gitlab-runner user to ec2-user group. This might work.

The official doc says the following:

Scripts you specify in after_script execute in a new shell, separate
from any before_script or script commands. As a result, they:

Have the current working directory set back to the default (according to the variables which define how the runner processes Git requests).
Don’t have access to changes done by commands defined in the
before_script or script, including:

Command aliases and variables exported in script scripts.
Changes outside of the working tree (depending on the runner executor), like software installed by a before_script or script script.


Have a separate timeout. For GitLab Runner 16.4 and later, this defaults to 5 minutes, and can be configured with the RUNNER_AFTER_SCRIPT_TIMEOUT variable. In GitLab
16.3 and earlier, the timeout is hard-coded to 5 minutes.
Don’t affect the job’s exit code. If the script section succeeds and the after_script times out or fails, the job exits with code 0 (Job Succeeded).
There is a known issue with using CI/CD job tokens with
after_script. You can use a job token for authentication in
after_script commands, but the token immediately becomes invalid if
the job is cancelled. See issue for more details.


To solve this you must change the directory in each runner step, separately, like this:
    stages:
        - build

    pull-repository-job:
        stage: build
        tags:
            - ci
            - shell
            
        only:
            - master
            
        script:
            - cd /home/ec2-user/deployer/safety/httpdocs
            - echo "Start Deploy"
            - echo "Finished Build and Deploy"

Doc also says the following:

Generally it’s unsafe to run jobs with shell executors. The jobs are
run with the user’s permissions (gitlab-runner) and can “steal” code
from other projects that are run on this server. Depending on your
configuration, the job could execute arbitrary commands on the server
as a highly privileged user. Use it only for running builds from users
you trust on a server you trust and own.

So I suggest you create a group that allows access to the folder for the user who needs to access the profile folder and insert the runner user into it.
You can also set a custom build dir using this (doc):
    variables:
      GIT_CLONE_PATH: $CI_BUILDS_DIR/project-name

I hope this helps!
